# Borderless Transparent QWidget' content not drawn when put inside another QWidget

Tags: c++, windows, qt, gdi, qpainter

In my project, I need to place a window inside the window containing the program icons on **Windows** desktop.

The specific method is to use the **Windows** API to find the handle of that window, and then set the window I want to place as its child window.

```
BOOL enumWindowFindDesktopIconWindow(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    long wflags = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
    if (!(wflags & WS_VISIBLE))
        return TRUE;
    HWND sndWnd;
    if (!(sndWnd = FindWindowEx(hwnd, NULL, "SHELLDLL_DefView", NULL)))
        return TRUE;
    HWND targetWnd;
    if (!(targetWnd = FindWindowEx(sndWnd, NULL, "SysListView32", "FolderView")))
        return TRUE;
    HWND* resultHwnd = (HWND*)lParam;
    resultHwnd = hwnd;
    return FALSE;
}

HWND findDesktopIconWindow()
{
    HWND resultHwnd = NULL;
    EnumWindows((WNDENUMPROC)enumWindowFindDesktopIconWindow, (LPARAM)&resultHwnd);
    return resultHwnd;
}

void setWindowToIconLayer(HWND winID)
{
    setWindowNormal(winID);
    HWND desktopHwnd = findDesktopIconWindow();
    if (!desktopHwnd)
        return ;
    SetParent(winID, desktopHwnd);
}
```

The above is the method of placing a window into the icon layer.

During this process, I encountered a problem: If the window being placed has the properties of transparency and no border, it will not be drawn.

After some testing, although the window is not drawn, all events of the buttons on the window (which are not drawn) can be responded to, which is very strange.

Later, I did some testing in `paintEvent()` and found that `paintEvent()` was called correctly. Also, what I drew using **GDI** functions in the **Windows** API could be displayed correctly on the window, but not what was drawn using `QPainter`, which is very strange.

Finally, I used the `QWidget::grab()` function to capture a screenshot of the window, and the result was correct, which left me at a loss.

Before this, I raised an issue to Qt, but after a year, the problem has not been resolved.

I would like to ask if there is any way to avoid or solve this problem?

[bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-102145) link provided. This problem can be reproduced by following the code in the link.